# How to make graphs within tables in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphics

Im looking for something like the table at https://coinmarketcap.com/. What would be the easiest way to make this graph? I will be using datapoints present elsewhere in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It's called a 'sparkline'

You can find the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline). It's generally a very small chart, usually used in a table.

#### An appropriate jQuery library

Making sparklines in JavaScript is a little complicated, and it is best to use a library. A jQuery plugin perfect for your needs can be found [here](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about). Once you've imported it, you can do:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sparklines/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".inlinesparkline").sparkline();
        $(".inlinesparkline-large").sparkline("html", { width: "300px", height: "75px" });
    });
</script>

Default
<p class="inlinesparkline">1,4,5,4,4,6,6,7,8</p>

Large
<p class="inlinesparkline-large">1,4,5,4,4,6,6,7,8</p>
```

If these are too small for you, the size can be changed too. See the [Common Options](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#common) for the plugin.